# How to get % cpu and % memory of process during OpenSSL encryption

Tags: command-line, openssl, top

I am running an OpenSSL script. How to get % cpu and % memory? Normally I am using `top` command in other terminal. `top` is returning % CPU and % memory but for noting down it is taking time. Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `time` command for this purpose too :)

```
command time -f "\nElapsed: %E \nUser: %U \nSystem: %S \nMemory: %M\n" [your command/script here] 1> /dev/null
```

with `top` you can do something like:

```
top -p [pid of your process] -b > log
```

e.g:

```
top -p `pidof openssl` -b > log
```

Comment: @Ravexina I tried the first command, but always getting `0.00` for CPU usage:
`command time -f "\nElapsed: %E \nUser: %U \nSystem: %S \nMemory: %M\n" openssl speed -multi $(nproc --all)`